# Is there any alternative to Intel's PoET in hyperledger sawtooth?

Tags: intel, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I found that hyperledger sawtooth besides PoET also works with [RAFT](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/raft/nightly/master/introduction.html). And I was wondering if there any other consensus algorithms compatible with HyperLedger Sawtooth?

Answer (score 2):

Sawtooth supports DevMode (for development use only) and PoET (both with and without SGX).

PBFT is in the works, but not yet released.
Remme.io uses Sawtooth and wrote another custom consensus algorithm.